# Customer Propensity Model using GA4 - Bigquery

Tags: machine-learning, google-analytics, google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

I have replicated https://cloud.google.com/architecture/predicting-customer-propensity-to-buy in GA4. I am trying to predict if a user will purchase on a return visit.

Could you please go let me know where I am going wrong?

The code I have developed -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE bqml.propensity_data AS
SELECT
    user_pseudo_id,
    session_engaged,
    engagement_time_msec,
    will_buy_on_return_visit
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            user_pseudo_id,
            IFNULL(cast( (select value.string_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'session_engaged') AS int64),0) as session_engaged,
            IFNULL((select value.int_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'engagement_time_msec'),0) as engagement_time_msec
        FROM 
            `ga4bigquery.analytics_250157330.events_*`
        WHERE 
            event_name = 'first_visit'
        AND event_date BETWEEN '20210308' AND '20210506'
    )
    JOIN (
        SELECT  
        user_pseudo_id,
        IF(
            COUNTIF( ecommerce.purchase_revenue > 0 AND event_name != 'first_visit' ) > 0, 1,0) AS will_buy_on_return_visit
        FROM 
            `ga4bigquery.analytics_250157330.events_*`
        GROUP BY
         user_pseudo_id
        order by will_buy_on_return_visit desc
    )
USING(user_pseudo_id)
ORDER BY  will_buy_on_return_visit DESC;
```

https://cloud.google.com/architecture/predicting-customer-propensity-to-buy:
Actual code -

```
# select initial features and label to feed into your model
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE bqml.propensity_data AS
  SELECT
    fullVisitorId,
    bounces,
    time_on_site,
    will_buy_on_return_visit
  FROM (
        # select features
        SELECT
          fullVisitorId,
          IFNULL(totals.bounces, 0) AS bounces,
          IFNULL(totals.timeOnSite, 0) AS time_on_site
        FROM
          `data-to-insights.ecommerce.web_analytics`
        WHERE
          totals.newVisits = 1
        AND date BETWEEN '20160801' # train on first 9 months of data
        AND '20170430'
       )
  JOIN (
        SELECT
          fullvisitorid,
          IF (
              COUNTIF (
                       totals.transactions > 0
                       AND totals.newVisits IS NULL
                      ) > 0,
              1,
              0
             ) AS will_buy_on_return_visit
        FROM
          `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.*`
        GROUP BY
          fullvisitorid
       )
  USING (fullVisitorId)
  ORDER BY time_on_site DESC;
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific about your question? Exactly where are you facing the issue? Is your query returning an error or is it returning something you are not expecting?

Comment: Sorry @MinhazKazi. I was not able to replicate the exact model in GA4 as it was in GA3 (https://cloud.google.com/architecture/predicting-customer-propensity-to-buy).

Comment: If you are using a GA4 property, this might be a better guide to follow: https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/churn-prediction-game-developers-using-google-analytics-4-ga4-and-bigquery-ml